When i run my app in a docker container file pathes get messed up
public File convert(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        byte[] bytes;
       try {
           bytes = multipartFile.getBytes();
           try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("files/" + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename())) {
               fos.write(bytes);
           }
       } catch(IOException e) {
           System.out.println("Exception when converting multipart file to array of bytes");
           System.out.println(e.getCause());
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
        return new File("files/" + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
    }

I have this method which converts MultipartFile to File (from .io package). files/ is a directory inside my project base directory.Everything works fine on my local machine (ubuntu 22),  but when i run the app in a docker container and call this method it throws IOException:
file-exchange-web-1       | Exception when converting multipart file to array of bytes
file-exchange-web-1       | null
file-exchange-web-1       | files/zip.png (No such file or directory)

Here is what happens when i am trying to reach this file:
file-exchange-web-1       | java.io.FileNotFoundException: file [/apps/files/zip.png] cannot be resolved in the file system for checking its content length

Here is my dockerfile:
FROM openjdk:21-slim

WORKDIR /apps
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY target/${JAR_FILE} /apps/app.jar
COPY /entrypoint.sh /apps/entrypoint.sh

RUN adduser --system servuser
RUN chmod +x /apps/entrypoint.sh
RUN chown -R servuser /apps

USER servuser
EXPOSE 8080 8080
CMD ["/apps/entrypoint.sh"]

I understand that dockerfile changes the working directory to /apps and it changes the path but I do not really understand what exactly WORKDIR does: where does it create the /apps directory, in which directory in the container is my app and etc. I also heard about using System.getProperty("user.dir"); but i do not really understand where is my app located in the container so it does not make a lot of sense for me.
I googled the concept of exact directories docker puts the app in a container but did not really find anything that could help me.
Edited*
Changing dockerfile solved my problem:
FROM openjdk:21-slim
WORKDIR /apps
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY target/${JAR_FILE} /apps/app.jar
COPY /entrypoint.sh /apps/entrypoint.sh
RUN adduser --system servuser
RUN chmod +x /apps/entrypoint.sh
RUN chown -R servuser /apps
RUN mkdir files
USER root
EXPOSE 8080 8080
CMD ["/apps/entrypoint.sh"]

I think WORKDIR is just for what with in docker file. You can figure the path out by print out the current directory like new File(".")

I’m going to guess that the problem is that the files directory doesn’t exist within the Docker container.

You were right, I forgot to create it
Thank you :)

You are setting the WORKDIR when building the docker image and that makes sure that all RUN commands use the same path.
There should be a file under root created i.e. /apps but when you actually run the docker image you also need to specify /apps as your work directory using the -w option.
A way to troubleshoot such problems is doing:  docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash and you can look the directory structure in your image and what exists there

Thank you much, I figured out the problem was that I did not create the files directory in apps/. I added this two commands                                                                                                RUN mkdir files
USER root                                                                                                                                         and now it works fine for me

docker run -w and WORKDIR both set the same thing, the current directory in the container.  IME it's pretty rare to need docker run -w.
